# What does $p+q \leq 1$ means in the context of $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras, algebraic-k-theory

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and let $p,q \in A$. The book I'm following(An Introduction to K-theory for $C^*$-algebra) has this notation $p+q \leq 1$.

What does this mean? I looked through the book, but it seems like I have missed where they explained this notation.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Is it the $1$, because the $C^\ast$-algebrais not necessarily unital? Or don't you know how the order in a $C^\ast$-algebra is defined?

Comment: @MaoWao I don't know how the order is defined yes

Comment: Then I can only support the point from Martin's answer. If you are not familiar with the basics of $C^\ast$-algebras, you're gonna have a hard time learning about their $K$-Theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a C$^*$-algebra, $a\leq b$ means that $b-a$ is positive.

As a comment/advice, the book you are reading has this as its very first paragraph:

> This chapter contains some basic facts about C*-algebras that the reader is
> assumed to be (or become) familiar with. There are very few proofs given in
> this chapter, and the reader is referred to other sources, for example Murphy's
> book [29], for details.

This book is written for someone already familiar with C$^*$-algebras, with a focus on K-theory. In my personal opinion, you should get some proficiency in C$^*$-algebras first.